# Why YSlow is not detecting my cookie-free domains?

Tags: performance, pagespeed, yslow, gtmetrix

I have moved all my static assets to cloudfront.net, and when I view my source code, my CSS and JS and images are already hosted in cloudfront.net. But when I check GTmetrix.com, my use cookie-free domains is still graded F, and my main domain is still showed in the list, instead of cloudfront.

[image: Actual source code. Already using cookie-free domains]
[image: Yslow results at GTmetrix. It doesn't show my cloudfront.net URLs]

I already cleared my cache, cloudflare cache, browser cache, and all kinds of cache, but Yslow in GTmetrix still doesn't detect that I'm using a CDN (cloudfront.net).

Anyone here who encountered the same problem?

Actual GTMetrix Result:
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.flyskyjetair.com/SgHBKXsJ

Actual Code:
view-source:https://www.flyskyjetair.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the strip cookies and cache cookies options enabled however when running your site through YSlow are still receiving a warning, this is due to a YSlow false-positive. If you set your cookies on the top-level domain (e.g. yourwebsite.com) all of your subdomains will also include the cookies that are set. This also includes your custom CDN URL if using one (e.g. cdn.yourwebsite.com).

However, as long as you have the strip cookies option enabled, even if you receive this warning it will be incorrect. YSlow does not take into consideration that the CDN actually strips the cookie and therefore may continue to throw the error. However, if you run a cURL command on the asset or check it within the Chrome Dev tools Network tab, you won’t see any Set-Cookie headers. Therefore this YSlow warning can be safely ignored.
If you are using Cloudflare then you simply won’t be able to achieve 100 on YSlow. Cloudflare appends a __cfduid cookie to every request which cannot be removed due to security reasons.